# Appending big html file to modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to append large amount of HTML(around 10k lines) to bootstrap modal.

```
async function generatereport(){
    $('#ProfilingReport').empty();
    let BIGHTML = await GenerateBIGHTML();
    $("#ProfilingReport").append(BIGHTML);
}
```

And html

```
<div class="modal-body" id="#ProfilingReport">
        </div>
```

However the modal is still empty after the function has finished running.
Is there a way to append big amount of html to a modal or a window?

Comment: Did you console log out BIGHTML to see if it returns a value?
What does GenerateBIGHTML() do?

Comment: yes it generates value, i actually was able to append this to normal div however i want to append it to the modal doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `#` selector is used when call the data from div or to pass data into div in jQuery

You need to remove the `#` symbol from div's `id="#ProfilingReport"`

```
<div class="modal-body" id="ProfilingReport">
</div>
```

Reference:
https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/